# Automatically update and render item quantity on cart update

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-views

I have been working on my cart functionality but I cannot seem to get the cart item.quantity to automatically update without a page refresh.

I'm wondering how I could modify the code below to not only update my CartIcon but update specific item quantity too or whether I need a new function/util entirely.

Here is the HTML snippet with the variable {{item.quantity}} I would like to automatically update when the quantity is changed.

```
<svg class="icon--cart change-quantity update-cart" data-product="{{item.product.id}}" data-action="add" >
                    <use href="/media/sprite.svg#plus-solid"/>
                </svg>
                {{item.quantity}}
                <svg class="icon--cart change-quantity update-cart" data-product="{{item.product.id}}" data-action="remove">
                    <use href="/media/sprite.svg#minus-solid"/>
                </svg>
```

Here is a util I made for updating the Cart Icon number in my header:

```
@login_required
def get_cart_quantity(request):
    cart = get_object_or_404(Cart, user=request.user)
    quantity = sum(item.quantity for item in cart.items.all())
    return JsonResponse({'quantity': quantity})
```

Here is my current script that successfully updates my CartIcon:

```
function updateCartQuantity() {
  fetch("/get_cart_quantity/")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      document.getElementById("cart-quantity").textContent = data.quantity;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error fetching cart quantity:", error);
    });
}

// Call updateCartQuantity when the page loads and after adding an item to the cart
window.addEventListener("load", updateCartQuantity);
```

Below is the quantity field I want to automatically update, so it is specific to the item, not the whole cart quantity.

[image]